# Echo '$(VAR)' to a file

Tags: makefile, echo

I have the following problem with a line from a Makefile:

```
echo 'include $(BASE)/Makefile.base' > file
```

If I write this directly into the console it literally prints 'include $(BASE)/Makefile.base' into the file, but when using it within a Makefile $(BASE) always gets replaced with a blank and i want it to literally write that to the file. I tried to write several ways but can't seem the find the right way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo 'include $$(BASE)/Makefile.base' > file
```

The macro named `$` (invoked using `$$`) expands to `$`.  You frequently need to use `$$` in segments of a `makefile` that will become shell script, because `make` expands `$L`, `$(NAME)` and `${NAME}` (where `L` is a single-letter) automatically (to an empty string if the macro isn't set to anything else).